# How do I add different users to a single repo which has multiple remotes?

Tags: git

I have one local repo which has 2 different remotes, each of which requires a different username/password to connect to. When I push to origin I never have to enter my username (this is the origin for most of my projects), however when pushing to the second remote it always requires me to enter a username as well. Is there a way to associate a username with a given remote in the settings?

Here is the config for my repo:

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = false
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
        symlinks = false
        ignorecase = true
        hideDotFiles = dotGitOnly
[remote "origin"]
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
        url = git@codebasehq.com:namehere/project/repo-name.git
[branch "master"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/master
[branch "develop"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/develop
[remote "second"]
        url = https://github.com/project/second-repo-name.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/second/*
```

Comment: Are you using a `--global` config?

Comment: Yes. However the only info in there is my name (display) and email address.

Comment: Can you post your `git config` for your repo?

Comment: Updated my question with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using a solution posted by Linus Torvalds on the [git mailing list](http://marc.info/?l=git&m=116231242118202&w=2) that works quite well and can be applied to your situation easily.

You can add a merged-remote for "origin" and "second" repos:

```
[remote "merged"]
        url = git@codebasehq.com:namehere/project/repo-name.git
        url = https://username:password@github.com/project/second-repo-name.git
```

Then you can do a `git push merged/Master` and it will push to both `origin/Master` and `second/Master`. Obviously you can add whatever other config options for the respective repos as well, user, password and such.

Comment: I don't want to push to both at the same time, though. My question wasn't how to push to two different repos, I want to just have git remember the username to the second one like it does with the first.

Comment: @Scott - I've updated the code. If you look at the second url you will see how you can send your credentials via https and of course this could be used wherever you want, not just in my `remote` example.

Comment: Ah that does it. Thanks!